# xcode swift UICollectionView layout - cell sizing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make the cells of a collection view show up with equal spacing between themselves and sides, having a hard time figuring out how to do this with AutoLayout so I wrote a piece of code that detects the screen width and picks a specific reusable cell to use, from 3 designs of 200, 150 and 100 px (possibly thinking to add/remove more stuff like icons, text whatever, depending on their width so I kind of want this strange approach)

[image: code]

The reusable cells are:

[image: cells]

This actually works quite nice on most devices, at least on the simulator, for instance here's the view on 5s

[image: iphone 5s capture]

but on the iPhone 6 here's what happens:

[image: iphone 6 capture]

Naturally, I'd like to have them space out evenly on all devices.

I tried playing with layout.minimumInteritemSpacing but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction. I know there are tons of AutoLayout guides and questions around but I've just started playing with Swift a few days ago and although there are quite a lot of answers out there, none seems to apply exactly to this case.

TIA

Comment: Thanks for this! I took sort of an opposite approach to your answer to this. I determined the spacing and insets I wanted first, and then based on those parameters, figured out the item sizes  that would work for each device size. That eliminated the need for the spacing calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's how I just got this to work:

1) I calculated the number of cells fitting the screen

2) calculated available space

```
var available_ spacing = screenWidth % cell_width
```

2) calculated the number of spaces including intra-item margins and collection "paddings", it's basically num_cells -1 + 2 (the borders)

3) divided the available space and added the resulting figure to both left and right borders in the sectionInset definition, but also between the cells using minimumInteritemspacing

The cells are now laid out nice with even spacing and borders. Hope this helps someone else... as I've been playing with this for a few hours before decided to post here.

<3 !